# "what" instead "why"

Tags: usage

In "Red Rock Mystery" book there is the text:

> Before she had been locked away, before her cries for help, she remembered daylight, soft and pure and warm. Now it felt a world away.
>   **What** parents could do this to their own flesh and blood?

For me it would be fine if there would be "Why parents could do this to their own flesh and blood?". Can you explain to me why in last sentence there is "what" instead of "why"?

Comment: "**What** kind of parents could do this?" (Implied answer - only bad ones.) It's a slightly different question from "Why would parents do this?"

Comment: "Why parents could do this to their own flesh and blood?" is not grammatical.

Comment: Some fragments are acceptable in informal registers, but this (Why parents could do this to their own flesh and blood?) lacks the necessary context.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree with you but it could also be said that the "what" was more like "which" than "why". The OP's sentence could have been written as "Which parents could do this?"